# Android Studio Gradle error "Multiple dex files define..."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

My Project was working fine, when I have added facebook sdk into my project I have an error like this, I have tried so many ways to fix this, but I didn't. What should I do?

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class
```

My App gradle is below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

And here is the facebook build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
    // The version will be derived from source
    project.version = null
    def sdkVersionFile = file('src/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
    sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
        def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
        if (matcher.matches()) {
          project.version = matcher[0][1]
          return
        }
    }
    if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
      throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
            artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'Facebook Android SDK'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

            scm {
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'facebook'
                    name 'Facebook'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
    required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}
```

Comment: Based on the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694355/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lbolts-aggregateexception and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059838/duplicate-zip-entry-after-gradle-plugin-v0-13-1 , you seem to need to exclude the module from the Facebook SDK dependency `exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-android'` please try this

Comment: I guess in your my app build.gradle your libs folder includes "support-v4" jar of different version. Try to remove that and run it again...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Where should I add exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-android'

Comment: I have solved this with "multiDexEnabled=true" but now given error as follow  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class

Comment: `compile project(':facebook') { exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-android' }` if it works

Comment: Are you doing any updates to Facebook SDK? If not you can link it in from maven as well: `compile com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0`. Similarly you can bring in the bolts jar from maven, and it should dedupe..

Comment: I have tried both of them but still continue.

Comment: any update on this? i tried `compile (project(':FacebookSDK')) { exclude (group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-android') }` but still the same

Answer (score 19):

Now they split bolts-android into bolts-applinks and bolts-tasks .so you need exclude both from the gradle build

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'){
exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
        module: 'bolts-tasks'
exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
        module: 'bolts-applinks';}
```

This works perfectly for me !!!!

Comment: well done, with the new facebook sdk only this solution works, if I have chance I will give 2+. Thanks it save me a time

Answer (score 15):

For me, I was adding Facebook SDK as a project, and set it as dependencies.

However, the exclude work after i switching to use the maven source.

I think it is for maven only, not for project dependencies? (please provide correct info if someone know about this)

In other word, you can now delete the Facebook SDK project and files.

remember to add

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

if you weren't using maven.

So the build.gradle look like this, I commented out the project way.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0'){
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
//    compile (project(':FacebookSDK')){
//        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
//        exclude module: 'support-v4'
//    }
    compile (project(':UserVoiceSDK')){ exclude module: 'support-v4' }
}
```

Comment: This is not answer of my question.

Comment: Tks. This solved like a boss my problem. mdemir I believe you did not understand the response of @Shing. After all, I came here with the same doubt you.

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar problem. This was really frustrating for me because everything worked fine and suddenly it broke for no reason.

The issue is hinted in `duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class`. It's a clash of the Bolts library, used by Facebook and Parse.

For me, the problem lay in these two lines:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
```

I had downloaded the Parse libraries and put them in the `/libs/` folder. The problem was that there was another `bolts-android` file in that folder.

The solution is to delete that library and keep the `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'` part.

#### Alternative problem

In my case, I used `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'` instead of a specific version. This always takes the latest version. So when `bolts` upgraded to version `1.2.0`, the thing just seemed to randomly break because all of a sudden the version in the `/libs/` folder and the latest version no longer aligned.

Best practice is to avoid `1.+` style versioning and just keep checking and updating to the latest version every now and then.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

no need to remove any jar files. In Gradle file we have written these two lines

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
```

just remove

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

because we are compiling all the jar files and then again including the bolts to compile due to which the error is shown

Answer (score 0):

in my case the i had added a .jar in the library code . the library in turn gets used in the main app . the dex was still in the cache file even if i had cleaned my project and installed it . To be sure in the main app you can check the count of the library . The cache file is "Project -> build -> dex-cache -> cache.xml" . If you have multiple counts of the library then u need to do this in Android Studio -> File -> invalidate cache / restart