# Android Studio - ProGuard IOException Duplicate Zip Entry

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

So I am trying to set up ProGuard in Gradle for my Android Studio project and I get the following error when building the project:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Rich\Desktop\WebProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\Roomie\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\debug\classes.jar] (Can't read C:\Users\Rich\Desktop\WebProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\Roomie\app\libs\bolts-android-1.1.4.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [a/a.class == bolts-android-1.1.4.jar:bolts/AggregateException.class]))

Here is my proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }

-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.**

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For futur reference :

I stumbled upon the same problem and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28889718/2087724) on SO helped me solved it.

Basically when you include libraries in your project, some of them contain common dependencies and this is why proguard fails with an IOException.

My problem was that I used *Parse* and *Facebook* SDKs and both of them imported bolts library as a dependency.
Simply adding some **exclude** directives when importing one of the conflicting SDKs solved the problem :

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0') {
    exclude module: 'bolts-android'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you point the problem. Simply said, the problem caused by:
You have two dependencies A and B,  but the library A depends on B too, so, your project contains two same libraries: B. It causes Conflict.