# Gradle failed with Facebook SDK, Fresco lib and Retrofit?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, retrofit2, fresco

Did anyone tried to implement Facebook SDK and Fresco lib and Retrofit?
My gradle fails with duplicate about bolts.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:  java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:    bolts/AggregateException.class
```

This is my gradle fail. I tried with Fresco for OkHttp, but still I get the problem above.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp:0.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: See if anything here helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791817/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define

Comment: I have tried that link, but no luck. Any other idea?

Comment: I saw in the comments there was an `exclude` in the gradle on the bolts project. I've seen a couple posts now about that library conflicting with *something*, not sure what...

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what helped me:

```
compile ('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0+'){
    exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-applinks';
    exclude module: 'bolts-android';
    exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-tasks';
}
```