# Android Studio - Gradle dependencies - How to Exclude `bolts` from `facebook`?

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, epson, android-multidex

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     bolts/AggregateException.class

That's how the error looks like. I know that `bolts` is used in 3 of my dependencies, `com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0`, `com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1` and a jar `ePOS2.jar`.

I have tried multiple solutions, starting with

```
 compile('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0') {
         exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-android'
     }
```

But I still get the error. I have also tried to exclude some parts from `com.parse:parse-android1.13.1` as shown [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791817/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define)  but then I get the missing classes error then.

I also enabled `multidex` as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library) but the error still occurs.

I tried to exclude `com/parse/bolts/AggregateException.class` as shown [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575474/gradle-how-to-exclude-a-particular-package-from-a-jar), still the error occurs.

The strangest is that if I enable `InstantRun` I can run the app but crashes when it uses a certain class from the jar.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader

So, I thought if is possible to exclude that certain class `AggregateException.class` either from jar or `com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1`?

**EDIT**

> compile('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0') {
>           exclude module: 'bolts-android'
>       }

OR

> compile('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0') {
>           exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
>                   module: 'bolts-android'
>       }

I have tried to exclude `bolts` from `com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0` but whatever I do they still appear:

```
    +--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1                                  
+--- com.android.support:design:23.3.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.3.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0
+--- com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1
+--- com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.10.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.10.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.10.0
|    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.10.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.3.0 (*)
|         +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|         +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.10.0
|         +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:0.10.0
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.3.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.10.0
|         |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4 !!! HERE
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4  !!! HERE
+--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp:0.7.0
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.3.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.7.0 -> 0.10.0 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.7.0 -> 0.10.0
+--- com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
\--- uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0
     \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.3.0 (*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `duplicate entry` error ususally originates from the packager trying to package multiple different versions of the same class.

It seems that you've only excluded a specific part of the bolts library. This causes your build to mix 2 different version of the remaining parts of the library, which probably do still have some overlapping classes.

In my project I've excluded the whole library from every module, and then forced a unified bolts version to rule them all.

In my gradle build I've exluded bolts from all modules dependant on bolts, like this:

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts'
}
```

And then forced all modules to use a the latest bolts:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
```

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 1):

I was having problem while generating APK, And I was using:

```js
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile ('com.sromku:simple-fb:4.1.1')
```

then I modified this to:

```js
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile ('com.sromku:simple-fb:4.1.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts'
    }
```

and It worked like a CHARM!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Code-only answers are not very helpful.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you solved someone's problem. Congratulations! As @JoeC wrote, adding an explanation would make your answer even more valuable.