# I can't generate signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I want to update my app, but when I try to generate a signed apk, I receive an error with these messages:

> Warning:warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type
>   'GuardedBy': class file for javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy not
>   found
>
> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lbolts/AppLink$Target;
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 2

Please help!!

Comment: Are you using Facebook also?

Comment: @Giru Bhai Yes, I'm using Facebook sdk

Comment: Then here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27695724/991085 or check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35550829/991085

Comment: @Giru Bhai but I also use Facebook SDK in my older version which working fine

Comment: try to remove redundant dependencies...if you found any.

Comment: @gvsharma I don't find any

Comment: Turn out I do have duplicate library in library :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **`multiDexEnabled true`** like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

> **EDIT :**
>   And if you don't know which part to exclude just add below code to
>   your build.gradle just below `defaultConfig`:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
```

Comment: Why need to enable multiDex?

Comment: As you have used Facebook SDK the number of methods in your project may be more than 65,000. `multiDex` solved my problem so i referred you the same.

Comment: If I enable it, I need to use multiDex library and do some config too right?

Comment: library for multiDex?? sorry, i haven't heard this before. I think there is no library for `multiDex`.

Comment: I'll test it and tell you

Comment: Yes, it work, but I also need to exclude duplicate library like @Giru Bhai commented

Comment: You can use it by excluding duplicate part. as explained in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35550829/6127411